# SwiftUI: Better way of changing NavigationBarTitle based TabbedView label

Tags: swift, swiftui

I was *finally* able to figure out how to change my `NavigationView`'s title based on the current tab in `TabbedView` using `onAppear()`, but I'm pretty sure that's not the way to go about it:

```
struct SomeTabbedView : View {
  @State private var selection = 0
  @State private var title = "First"
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      TabbedView(selection: $selection) {
        ContentView()
          .tabItemLabel(
            Text("First")
          ).tag(0).onAppear{
            self.title = "First"
        }

        OtherView()
          .tabItemLabel(
            Text("Second")
          ).tag(1).onAppear{
            self.title = "Second"
          }
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text(title))
      }
    }
}
```

In short, this violates the DRY principle pretty badly. If we decide to change the first view, for example, the string "First", the current implementation would require to repeat that in three different places.

I thought of initializing an array of dictionaries and loop over `View: Label` pairs, but not only am I not sure it's the right way, I'm not sure how to proceed with implementing it. It is also possible to just have an array with labels, but that creates another violation in case we want to change the order of views.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your top level view should be the `TabbedView`, and each tab should get its own `NavigationView`. This doesn't address the fact that "First" is used for both the `.navigationBarTitle` and the `.tabItemLabel`, but those are in fact two different things that can be different.

```
struct SomeTabbedView : View {
    @State private var selection = 0

    var body: some View {

        TabbedView(selection: $selection) {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView()
                    .navigationBarTitle(Text("First"))
            }
            .tabItemLabel(Text("First"))
            .tag(0)

            NavigationView {
                OtherView()
                    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Second"))
            }
            .tabItemLabel(Text("Second"))
            .tag(1)
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Voted but will keep this open for a while for answers that may address the DRYness of this. I fully agree that `.tabItemLabel` and `.navigationBarTitle` are conceptually (and often concretely) different, but I'd still like to know how would achieve this kind of view rendering inside a `forEach` loop, for example.

Comment: Actually with this proposed solution the contents of views will overlap with the NavigationBarTitle, while they don't in my implementation.

Comment: See [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html) "An app that uses a tab bar controller can also use navigation controllers in one or more tabs. When combining these two types of view controller in the same user interface, the tab bar controller always acts as the wrapper for the navigation controllers"

Comment: I see. So now my TabbedView is the parent of NavigationView, which is causing it not to reserve space for the NavigationBarTitle, but rather encapsulate it. Any idea how I can overcome this?

Comment: I do not know how to overcome that at this time.  It sounds like a great follow up question, assuming there isn't an answer out there already.

Comment: @zerohedge I just figured this out: You can make the title bar display correctly using .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top) on the TabbedView.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it by creating a view wrapper similar to what is done in SwiftUI.
This is basically just adding DRYness to [vacawama's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56553778/2161552):

```swift
struct NavigationTab<Title, Content>: View where Title: StringProtocol, Content: View {
    var title: Title
    var content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            content()
                .navigationBarTitle(Text(title))
        }
        .tabItemLabel(Text(title))
    }
}
```

I left the tag out because to me it makes more sense to have those defined in the parent view. You can use it like this:

```swift
struct SomeTabbedView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabbedView(selection: $selection) {
            NavigationTab(title: "First") {
                ContentView()
            }
            .tag(0)

            NavigationTab(title: "Second") {
                OtherView()
            }
            .tag(1)
        }
    }
}
```

This obviously gets more complicated if you want to have additional details like an image above the tab's label since `.navigationBarTitle()` requires a Text instance.